# Cannot find ngfactory,AOT webpack angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, aot

I've got angular soap app and i want to implement to it AOT compilation,problem is that im getting error like - 
Error: Cannot find module './components/home/home.module.ngfactory'.

im doing "node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json and then building vendor and webpack and starting application,there are no errors intime of building or creating compile aot folder,i think that problem is that loader looking for ngfactory file in main application,not compiled one.Can anyone explain how to tell loader to get ngfactory files right from aot folder,i tried to put ngfactory file for home component in my main app home folder and it gives other errors with imports in it,but it proove that its looks for ngfactory in main folder.
There is my tsconfig-aot.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
},
"exclude": [
    "ClientApp/boot-client.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
],
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "entryModule": "USWebTools.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
}
```

and webpack config

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const ngToolsWebpack = require('@ngtools/webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = () => {
    const isDevBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
const sharedConfig = {  
    stats: { modules: false },
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] }
        ] : [
                { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] }
            ])
    },
    plugins: [
        new CheckerPlugin()
    ]
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
        // Plugins that apply in development builds only
        new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
            filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
            moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
        })
    ] : [
            new ngToolsWebpack.AotPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig-aot.json',
                entryModule: helpers.root('USWebTools.Web/ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule')
            }),
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                beautify: false,
                comments: false,
                compress: {
                    screw_ie8: true,
                    warnings: false
                },
                mangle: {
                    screw_ie8: true
                }
            })

        ])
});

return [clientBundleConfig];
```